# Playing a second audio file after the first is completed, while addressing play() restrictions on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm building a webpage with a clock and a button that, when clicked or tapped, will play two files that 'say' the time. I'm having problems getting the two files to play sequentially; at the moment they both play essentially simultaneously.

I would really appreciate help with getting the mp3 files to play sequentially. At the moment they start at nearly the same time.

Here is my HTML, including the button that triggers the time to be played.

```
  <body onload="updateClock(); setInterval('updateClock()', 1000 )">
    <div style="clear: both;"> </div>
    <h1>What time is it?</h1>
    <p>Ideally this will have a button that will play the time.</p>
    <div id="clockcontainer">
      <span id="clock">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div id="voicebuttoncontainer">
      <button id="voicebutton" onclick="playSound(currentHours,currentMinutes)">Hear the time</button>
    </div>
```

The currentHours and currentMinutes parameters are part of a function that automatically updates the time on the page. This part seems to work smoothly at the moment, except for the audio files overlapping/not playing sequentially.

My JavaScript function reads:

```
// Function to play audio file
function playSound(hour,minute) {
    var path = "~/www/clock/recordings/"
    var hr = new Audio(path + hour + ".mp3");
    var mn = new Audio(path + minute + ".mp3");
    hr.play();
    mn.play();
}
```

If you have suggestions about ways to make mn play only after hr is complete I would appreciate them.

**UPDATE, 20 November 2017:** If you read the comment below, you'll see that @Cyber-Shadow very kindly helped solve this issue by identifying that I needed to attach an event handler to my first play() function. It was a huge help.

But a few weeks afterwards, I realised that my function wasn't working on mobile or desktop Safari. I received the following error message:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError (DOM Exception 35): The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

It seems to be related to Safari's (desktop and mobile) and other mobile browsers' limitation of auto-play. Eg here's Safari's announcement from June: https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/

In any case, to get around this restriction, I pulled my second play() function out of its nested function, so it was initially triggered in the same scope as the first play() function, and then I followed it up with a pause() function. More specifically, the function went from this:

```
// Function to play audio file
function playSound(hour,minute) {
    hr.play();
    $(hr).on("ended", function() {
      mn.play();
    });
}
```

...to this:

```
// Function to play audio file
function playSound(hour,minute) {
    hr.play();
    mn.play();  // NEW ROW
    mn.pause();  // NEW ROW
    $(hr).on("ended", function() {
      mn.play();
    });
}
```

Triggering the play function just after the first play function allowed me to utilise the event handler that is outlined in more detail below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use a jQuery event listener. It goes as follows:

```
$("hr").on("ended", function() {
mn.play();
});
```

This will track when the first audio finishes, so then you can play the second one.

Note: To be able to use jQuery, add this code to `<head>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @cyber-shadow - I'm probably overlooking something obvs here but can you give me a little more info on how to integrate this? 
I've tried modified my javascript in my original post so it reads:
 
        hr.play();
        $("audio").on("ended", function() {
          mn.play();
        });
    }
...but it's not working.

Comment: @scaffolding Glad I could help :)